# Mismatch between the processor architecture

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, compiler-warnings

I have an issue with these two famous warnings which are raised during compilation of our solution. There are many forums about these already and I read those, but they still don't solve my issue completely...

*1. There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "XXX", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.*

*2. Referenced assembly 'XXX' targets a different processor than the application.*

The reason why these appear in our case is clear. Our solution is compiled as AnyCPU and we want to keep it this way, as we do not want to compile it twice (once as x86 and second as x64). However, we use external DLL which is either x86 or x64 (it is not delivered as AnyCPU). 
We develop the application on 64bit windows, so we use the x64 DLL version as reference in the visual studio during development. When we deliver the application to end-users, the installer is customized to copy the proper DLL based on the platform of the target system, e.g. when it is installed on 64bit windows, it copies the x64 DLL version and when it is installed on 32bit windows, it copies the x86 DLL version. Therefore, we know that everything is finally ok, and we can ignore those messages. And therefore, I just want to make them disappear:-)

The first warning can be supressed by the following tag in the project file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>None</ResolveAssemblyWarnOrErrorOnTargetArchitectureMismatch>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But I did not find anywhere how to get rid of the other message? Is this possible as well? 
I know that this is just small issue and I can live with that. However, there is something like "Warning Free Build Initiative" going on in my company, so I'd like to get rid of all warnings we have.

Thank you in advance for any hints,
Tomas

Comment: Not much point in bringing this up over and over again.  This warning comes from the assembly linker, alink.dll, it has no option to suppress warnings.  If you don't want to see it again then you'll have to update your tooling.  Roslyn, aka VS2015, doesn't generate it anymore unless it is a gross mismatch.